# Select Command with Multiple LIKEs

Tags: asp.net, sql, search, select, gridview

**Functionality**

User inputs text into textboxA.
Search the database records for First Names AND Last Names corresponding to the user's input.

**The Problem:**

It appears the results I am getting are only searching "First Name" field and not BOTH the First Name and Last Name Fields

**Example:**

****A search for "Mike" returns:****

Mike Smith

Mike Jones

***A search for "Jones":***

Mike Jones is not returned

**CODE:**

```
Protected Sub button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

    If txtSearch.Text = "" Then

    Else

        Dim ConnString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("oakfratintdbConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(ConnString)
        Dim searchCMD As New SqlCommand("SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [MidInitName], [NameSuffix], [NamePrefix], [DOB], [DOD], [BurialDate], [GeoDirection], [Space], [Lot], [Row], [IntermentSpec], [AddtlInfo] FROM [OFCInterments] WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE @FirstName)", Conn)
        Dim searchDT As DataTable = GetData(searchCMD)
        GridView1.DataSource = searchDT
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

End Sub
```

**Code Explanation:**

txtSearch is the user's search input

Comment: Your WHERE clause is only looking at FirstName.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [MidInitName], [NameSuffix], [NamePrefix], [DOB], 
[DOD], [BurialDate], [GeoDirection], [Space], [Lot], [Row], [IntermentSpec], 
[AddtlInfo] FROM [OFCInterments] WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE @FirstName)
```

to

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [MidInitName], [NameSuffix], [NamePrefix], [DOB], 
[DOD], [BurialDate], [GeoDirection], [Space], [Lot], [Row], [IntermentSpec], 
[AddtlInfo] FROM [OFCInterments] WHERE ([FirstName] LIKE @FirstName or 
LastName like @LastName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the SQL query with the WHERE clause adjusted to give you the flexibility to search by only first name, only last name, or both.

```
SELECT [FirstName], [LastName], [MidInitName], [NameSuffix], [NamePrefix], [DOB], [DOD], [BurialDate], [GeoDirection], [Space], [Lot], [Row], [IntermentSpec], [AddtlInfo] FROM [OFCInterments] WHERE
    (@FirstName IS NULL OR [FirstName] LIKE @FirstName)
    AND (@LastName IS NULL OR [LastName] LIKE @LastName)
```

With this query I'm making the assumption that if the user searches for FirstName: "Mike" and LastName: "Jones" that the search results should only contain "Mike Jones", not "Mike Smith", "Mike Jones", and "Paul Jones".

Note that if you use this approach, you will need to make sure not to populate your parameters with an empty string in the case where the user did not supply a value for a criteria.  Alternatively, you could check for empty strings in the query in addition to null.

Comment: You could also wrap the parameters with the `LTRIM`, `RTRIM` and `NULLIF` functions to treat empty strings as NULL. For example: `NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(@LastName)), '')`